# python relative clock in loop

Tags: python, clock

Lets assume that we have a logging feature written in Python (maybe not relevant, but still) and the logging also notes the time in the log.

Then after some time in the never ending while loop, someone changes the system clock (either by the system itself of by sysadmin). Then of course all the timings are screwed up in the log (especially if the results are that the clock has been sent back some time).

Is there someway to prevent this by having a own relative clock in the whileloop? I was thinking of noting the time before the loop and then measure the iteration time in the loop and manually adding it to the saved time, but of course this drifts quite bad after some time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't measuring the "iteration time in the loop" also break when the user changes the system clock?

Comment: https://github.com/atdt/monotonic

Comment: Why not to use UNIX timestamp?

Comment: Are you talking about the sysadmin changing the timezone? If so always use utc and if you need a local time use a datetimeoffset.

Comment: Kevin: Probably...
tobias_k: I am ;-)
PadraicCunningham: no, changing the actual time...

Comment: @gregoff Use an NTP server?

Comment: what OS are you using? Also using the system time can also break with daylight savings, you can end up with the same time twice

Comment: This is an application where I cannot control the system clock on the server and cannot be sure if NTP sync is installed or not. This is built for linux-systems.

Comment: Are you just logging the time or time and date?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham both

Comment: Using the local server timezone?

Comment: @gregoff i guess you could use time before your loop as a reference point and then adjust in for each log with os.times()

Comment: @akalikin exactly what I was thinking after you answer before, thanks!

Comment: what about daylight savings? You cannot just add some amount  to a time and expect it to be correct

Comment: @PadraicCunningham daylight savings doesn't exist in UTC.

Comment: @gregoff. Where does it say you are using utc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working under UNIX system, `os.times()` does not get affected by change of system time:

> **os.times()**
>
> Return a 5-tuple of floating point numbers indicating accumulated
>   (processor or other) times, in seconds. The items are: user time,
>   system time, children’s user time, children’s system time, and elapsed
>   real time since a fixed point in the past, in that order. See the Unix
>   manual page times(2) or the corresponding Windows Platform API
>   documentation. On Windows, only the first two items are filled, the
>   others are zero.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.times()
(0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 17194492.75)
>>> os.times()[4]
17194500.18
```

Comment: I suspect that the first 4 elements are useless for OP's purposes and 5 will be affected by changing the system clock.

Comment: Actually, it looks like that os.times() is not being affected by a clock change. i tried to change the clock 10 seconds forward and my logging timestamp changed 10 seconds but the os.times only changed the iteration time. Might be the solution here!

Comment: @TobiaTesan it doesn't get affected by changing system time, that's the purpose

Comment: Silly me. it's the kernel clock. Sorry, disregard.

Comment: one further thought regarding this... it seems to fit my needs just perfectly, but i'm worried that the numbers this value produces will wrap around after a few months. any documentation available about this? I havn't been able to find anything.